# JSON Table Header Formatting

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload a CSV file into GBQ via JSON. However, there's multiple files and each file has a different header where the header may have special characters.

Is it at all possible to format the JSON to autodetect AND replace any special characters for the header?

JSON below:

```
{

  "configuration": {

    "load": {

      "destinationTable": {

        "projectId": "<var_destinationProject>",

        "datasetId": "<var_destinationDataset>",

        "tableId": "<var_destinationTable>_<var_date>"

      },

        "sourceUris": [

        "gs://<var_bucket>/<var_name>"

        ],

           "writeDisposition": "<var_writeDeposition>",
           "fieldDelimiter": "|",
           "skipLeadingRows": 1,
           "allowQuotedNewLines": true,
           "allowJaggedRows": true,
           "autodetect": true             

    }

  },

  "jobReference": {

    "jobId": "<var_get_job_id_return>"

  }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That should be handled prior to the API call by cleaning your data. From the API documentation, it does not seem there is an option to manage this through the API call. Let me know if you need more help (write the code to clean the data)